# Netbeans 15 run-remote on Raspberry Pi not working

Tags: netbeans-15

I have a NetBeans project which builds and runs remotely on my Raspberry Pi4 if I use Netbeans 12.5.
However, if I load the same project in Netbeans 15, it builds OK but does not deploy to Raspberry or run. Just a simple build.

Help!

Runs with Netbeans 12.5 but not Netbeans 15

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the problem. I'm using some javaFx classes in my project.
Version 12.5 In project->Properties->Build->deployment there is a signal checkbox "Enable Native Packaging ...." which I leave unchecked.
Version 15.0 In project->Properties->Build->deployment there are TWO check boxes. This first is the same as in 12.5, the second "Keep javaFx RT artifacts ..." needs to be checked.
Now version 15 works! I didn't understand that requirement.